# How to edit Visual Studio Code auto-complete in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I was coding on JavaScript when my instructor, **Andrew J. Mead** (I actually learn JS from Udemy) were telling about **try and catch**. I type slowly so I often use auto-complete given by VS Code. Anyway, I wrote **try** and in auto-complete it gave me **trycatch**. I clicked on it and it gave me this

```
try {

} catch (error) {

}
```

I want the **error** to be **e** like **catch(e)**, not **catch(error)**. Is there any way that I can edit VS Code's auto-complete?

Screenshots given

1. [trycatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJvIv.jpg)

[image: trycatch]

2. [auto-complete result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQo0k.jpg)

[image: auto-complete result]

3. [what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhiCX.jpg)

[image: what I want]

Thanks recently for the support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can create custom snippet for VS Code**
For do this, you need:

- Open snippet editor for js (open Command Palette (Ctrl-Shift-P) and print "Snippet", and then select "Configure user snippets", select "JavaScript")
- In the end of json paste:

```js
{
  ...
  "My Try-Catch block": {
    "prefix": "trycatch",
    "body": [
      "try {",
      "\t$0",
      "} catch (e) {",
      "\t",
      "}",
    ],
    "description": "Paste try-catch with e"
  }
}
```

Your snippet will be up than standard in autocomplete

---

**Or you can edit default snippets located at:**

```
%localappdata%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\javascript\snippets
```

In `javascript.code-snippets` file, but custom snippets is better way in any cases

Comment: but editing that file will be gone when the extension updates

Comment: rioV8, what do you mean by "when the extension updates"? What extension?